# Case thread ID - New format

Tags: case, salesforce-id, winter24

I have different processes in case of emails, to unsure mails will always go to the right case even if they are sent for different mail, I added a formula field in case which resolves threadId. It is working well but SF changed the format in the Winter 24 release.

does anyone have the formula for the new format ?

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeF6UAJ/case-thread-id-as-field-on-case-page-layout

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_service_email_refid_format_1.htm&release=246&type=5

Answer (score 0):

I have only very briefly, lightly tested this (less than 10 Cases) but this formula seems to work:

```
"ref:!"
&LEFT($Organization.Id,5)
&RIGHT($Organization.Id,5)
&".!"
&LEFT(Id,5)
&RIGHT(Id,6)
&":ref"
```

Comment: Thanks, but according to the release not the right part should count 10 chars , in your formula it is 11, it seems that in fact it is 11. but the left part in my org count 9 chars. 
Any idea why?

Comment: No idea, I did only try in one Salesforce org though.

Answer (score 0):

Release note seems wrong - looking at the ThreadId on an actual email, it is 11 and 11 chars (i.e. 11 for Ref and 11 for Org).
What I cannot work out is if the formula should be Left(5) and Right(6) or vice versa - as both give the same outcome currently due to a 0 being the char in either instance. Presumably, though, it might not always be a 0 in either instance as otherwise why would they have made this change to longer thread ids?
In any case, they are backwards compatible so currently do not have a need to update mine atm. Again, though, will that change...